# Toad -- seeing windows side by side

Tags: windows, database, text-editors, oracle-database, toad

I'd like to see the SQL editor in TOAD allow one to see windows side by side (as NotePad ++ allows with "move to other view", for example.)  My purpose would be to look at to different (but related) SQL query editing tabs, eg:  a.sql and b.sql .....

However, I don't see any way to do this.

I want to do this in the **same** **instance** of TOAD; I'm aware that one can open two instances, but this can get wasteful, and there is some uncertainty, e.g. if you have the same database session in each, etc.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: IIRC Toad has a tabbed document interface. can you drag a tab out of the main window?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, at least on my system.  I get:  <filename> is already loaded. Reload from disk? (Not useful for this purpose).

Comment: are you trying to look at the same object in both windows?

Comment: I'm wanting to look at editing SQL queries, different (but related) queries; I'll edit the question to make this more clear; thanks.

Comment: @FrankThomas, you also had an impressive career homerun total.